# Unicode in Java EE and save question mark in database

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, jdbc

When I insert persian information using Java EE 6 (JSF and JPA) my information save question mark for example "علی" ===> "???"  my database is Mysql and my table is UTF-8 . 
when insert persian data directly in database is correct and save correct.

I know that with change one property in Java EE my problem go to solved 
but I don`t know where is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with change in my.cnf (mysql configure file) in /etc/mysql (linux) and add this 2 tag solved my problem

```
default-character-set=utf8
default-collation=utf8_persian_ci
```

Comment: I suspect a bug in the MySQL JDBC driver.

Comment: For newer versions of mysql use the following:
```
[mysqld]
character-set-server=utf8
collation-server=utf8_general_ci
```

Answer (score 4):

I think that you need to set the following parameters in your connection URL:

```
jdbc:mysql://host:port/db?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8
```

Comment: i test this and set this in sun-resource.xml but not solved
<property name="URL" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/water_master? UseUnicode = true & characterEncoding = utf-8"/>

Comment: looks like you added spaces in that JDBC URL that you shouldn't have. Remove the spaces, e.g. do not write a space before and after the ?, = and & and write UTF-8 instead of utf-8.

Comment: I change sun-resources.xml but not solved
http://paste.ideaslabs.com/show/XWBCp5zl0Y

Comment: @Jeus I suggest trying to isolate the problem. So write a simple class using JDBC to validate the connection URL. Once you'll get it working, work on the app server configuration.

Comment: i use JPA and i dont have problem in insert data correctly in database with query browser mysql  but then insert with use my app insert ? in database

Comment: @Jeus I understood that so the MySQL setup seems ok. But is it working from Java? No? Is it a problem with the driver? You don't know. Is it a problem with the app server setup? You don't know. So try to isolate the problem, start with a simple Java class using JDBC to validate the behavior of the JDBC driver. Then work on the app server config.

Comment: i understand u and test all say u 
this is first app with jEE6 and already write other JSE app and this dosnt its problem with encoding . 
im run a already program for test again.
and this work correct .